# "no newline at end of file" C

Tags: c, sockets, virtual-machine

I'm using this command to compile:

`gcc –Werror –std=c99 client.c –o client`

CODE:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
#define PORT_NUM 8888

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

   while (1) 
   {
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        if((strncmp(buffer,"close",5) == 0 ))
            break;
        printf("Please enter the message: ");
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0) 
            error("ERROR writing to socket");
        bzero(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1);
        if (n < 0) 
            error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;

}
```

Trying to compile it in a shell on VM whos OS is linux
This error is driving me crazy, I don't understand what to do inorder to fix this.
I thought the client.c file is damaged, so I copied and pasted into a new .c file. When that failed, I wrote it from 0 and still getting this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to follow the advice and add a newline at the end of the file?

Comment: I didn't move the edited file into the shared directory. I was compiling the same file. 
Aaaaaaaaargh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text processing programs don't always agree on whether a `\n` character is *line separator* or *line terminator* - the difference being whether or not the last line in a file should be followed by a `\n` character or not.

I've never seen GCC complain about this, but you didn't indicate where the error is actually coming from.

You should be able to correct the situation by simply pressing ENTER after the last line in your file.

Alternatively, you could open, and them save the file using an editor like Vim, which considers it a line *terminator*.

As a matter of comparison, most UNIX tools also consider `\n` a line terminator, and include it after the final line. This allows one to `cat` a file without corrupting whatever follows (e.g. another file, the shell prompt, etc.)

Comment: Not sure, but I think I have some faint memory about reading something about gcc requiring LF at the last line, too. Not sure when it was, though, could be well >10 years ago. Anyway, I'd expect it to be obsolete now, but as my editor is configuered to add a newline anyway, it never occured to me.

Answer (score 2):

Add Enter (new line) behind the closing bracket.